# Can't connect to host using rtmfp

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmfp, adobe-cirrus

I have a p2p game using Adobe's rtmfp protocol and cirrus server. Everything seems to be working fine when I try it in stand alone flash player, but when I embed the game to the web page, suddenly nobody can't connect to my game. There are no errors, the connection just timeouts after a while.

here is how I create NetConnection on the host:

```
netConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.maxPeerConnections = 20;
netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
netConnection.connect("rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/3a34e[redacted]af45f80/");


public function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent) : void
{
    var peer:P2PNetPeer = null;
    switch(event.info.code) {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success": 
            streamOut = new NetStream(netConnection, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
            streamOut.client = {onPeerConnect:onPeerConnect};
            streamOut.publish(netConnection.nearID);
        break;
}
```

It's almost same on client side, except when I get NetConnection.Connect.Success I create inStream:

```
 streamIn = new NetStream(netConnection, farId);
 streamIn.client = {msg:onMessageReceived};
 streamIn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onInStreamStatus, false, 0, true);
 streamIn.play(farId);
```

This inStream is the one that causes problem, it never connects to the host specified by his farId (I pair players and exchange near/farIds using my own server) if the game is run from web page. When I run it locally using stand alone player, it connects almost immediatelly.

I am checking for other states and errors as well, but they are not important here (as said, I am not getting any errors, just timeout after a while)

Any idea what might be going on here?